# Forcing linking by name using CMake

Tags: c++, mongodb, c++11, msbuild

I have compiled Mongo C++11 drivers successful on Windows 10 64 bit using MSBuild. When trying to run a test got the error message;

```
The ordinal 4694 could not be located in the dynamic library libmongoc-1.0.dll
```

After a search on how to force linking C++ libraries by name I was pointed to CMake's [CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS.html) option.
After setting it within CMakeLists.txt for compiling Mongo C driver I still get the same error message, `set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS=ON)` . I tried to set it in all the Mongo drivers (BSON, C and C++) and still get the same error message. I also tried it on the CMake command line `-DCMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS=ON` and got the same error message.

Am I using this option for the intended purpose or is there a different option to set?

Comment: I am not sure of the behavior of `-D` option for non-cache variable, but correct syntax for `set` command is `set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)`. Try this syntax before any target declaration

Comment: Can you try replacing libmongoc-1.0.dll with just mongoc-1.0.dll (and similarly for libbson)?

Answer (score 0):

`CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS` defines *what* to export, not *how*. And in fact, it would be pointless to combine with exporting by ordinal. Exporting by ordinal basically numbers the exported functions. Obviously this requires a stable mapping, as the importing and exporting side have to agree. But `CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS` builds the export table on the fly, which isn't going to be stable.

The real problem here is why you're *importing* ordinals. That's a 1990's era optimization. Just use names.

Comment: I tried to use that CMake option after I got this error `The ordinal 4694 could not be located in the dynamic library libmongoc-1.0.dll`  from compiling the Mongo C++ library as it is, as such was trying to find a way to avoid that as well. Do you have any suggestion as to how I can avoid that? I did nothing to change the original source code in the first place.

Comment: @Amani: You're entirely missing my point here. The problem is the EXE, which is using `4694`. Why?

Comment: I bit not experienced when it comes to that area of C++. When compiling my EXE I did not specify anything to use `4694`. I just did call CMake like `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/install_mongo ../src`.

Comment: @Amani: Ok, last attempt: the problem is not with CMake, the problem is not with MongoDB. The problem is with that other program which you don't name.

Comment: please see my other question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635373/c-executable-keep-looking-for-ordinal-entry-point?noredirect=1#comment76256925_44635373)