# C++ executable keep looking for ordinal entry point

Tags: c++, mongodb, c++11, msbuild, mongo-cxx-driver

I have a C++ application with the below source code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/stdx.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>

using bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_array;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_document;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::document;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::finalize;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_array;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_document;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "\nJust to be sure!" << std::endl;

    // Making a connection to Mongo
    mongocxx::instance instance{};
    mongocxx::client client{mongocxx::uri{}};

    // Access a database
    mongocxx::database db = client["results"];

    std::cout << "\ndone." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it using the below CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(testing)

set(APP_SOURCES
    test.cpp
)

link_directories(../../installed_mongocxx/lib)
add_executable(testapp ${APP_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(testapp mongocxx bsoncxx)

target_include_directories(testapp PUBLIC 
                            ../../installed_mongocxx/include/mongocxx/v_noabi
                            ../../installed_mongocxx/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi
                            E:/Softwares/Libraries/Boost/boost_1_64_0
)

install(TARGETS testapp 
        DESTINATION bin)
```

I compile the program using MSBuild on Windows 10 64bit without errors, and upon running it gives this error;

```
The ordinal 4694 could not be located in the dynamic library libmongoc-1.0.dll
```

Is there anything wrong with the C++ code or CMakeLists.txt that could be explanation of the error?

Comment: ***Is there anything wrong with the C++ code or CMakeLists.txt that could be explanation of the error?*** I say no, this is a dll confilct. One example is using a dll that is the different than the import library.

Comment: @drescherjm, I also compile the libraries at the same time, so I do not see that as a possibility.

Comment: Do you have any chance of having a different copy of `libmongoc-1.0.dll` installed on your system?

Comment: @drescherjm, No, that is the only one. The full error message points to which library is trying to use; `The ordinal 4694 could not be located in the dynamic library E:\Projects\mongocxx\attempt_vs\installed_app\bin\libmongoc-1.0.dll`. So I'm sure it is using the one that has just been compiled.

Comment: I would try a clean build for that dll.

Comment: @drescherjm, did that several times with same error message.

Comment: I am out of ideas. I don't think this can be solved by changing the `CMakeLists.txt` however.

Comment: I notice that libmongoc and libbson are missing from the link directories and link libraries entries. Can you try adding them to see if that changes anything?

Answer (score 1):

That's unlikely. The question is what .LIB file you're using to link the DLL. When you build a DLL, that also creates a small .LIB file. This is basically just a table of contents. If you mix the .LIB file from one build with the .DLL from another build, you may run into incompatibilities.

In this case, the .LIB file will be taken from `../../installed_mongocxx/lib`, but the .DLL might not be. The DLL will be found at runtime, by Windows rules.

Comment: Got it! I'm cleaning everything now and start afresh.

Comment: I did a clean build of everything. When running the executable from cmd nothing happen. When opening the executable from WinDbg (64x) got the same error message.

Comment: @Amani: That suggests you find a different DLL in the second case. [DLL search rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I do not think so since the error message clearly point to the path of the DLL, which is the new one I created and there is no any other in my system.

Comment: At this point, I'd use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com). It's been the main tool to debug DLL loading issues for 2 decades.

Comment: Thank you, the Dependency Walker points to many missing "EXT-MS-WIN-***.DLL".

Comment: Ignore the errors about "EXT-MS-WIN-***.DLL" :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240215/dependency-walker-missing-dlls

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you've been asking a number of questions related to developing with mongocxx lately that all seem related. I encourage you to either ask a question on our [mongodb-user Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mongodb-user) or on our [Jira project](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CXX/), which will make it easier for us to assist you in any follow-up questions you might have without needing to have a conversation in multiple places.

(Apologies for posting this as an answer rather than a comment; StackOverflow seems to have a length limit on comments, and I couldn't fit this in one)

Comment: Really appreciated as I would really wish to use Mongo C++ in my project.